# ng-click not working for dynamically created datatable

Tags: angularjs, datatables

I am having a search textbox, a button and a datatable. Initially on page load, when table is created, `ng-click` is working fine and on click of search button i dynamically create the table again and show searched records in that(this is working fine). But on dynamically created table, `ng-click` is not working. Below is the code for the table which I am loading initially.

```
<div id="tableDiv" class="table-responsive" style="width: 100%;">
  <table id="srchTable" class="display" style="font-size: 0.85em;">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr ng-repeat="sData in searchData">
      <td><a id="A1" href="" ng-click="openDialog(sData.UserID)">{{jsonSearchData.Name}}</a></td>
      <td>{{sData.Age}}</td>
      <td>{{sData.Salary}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

`ng-click` is working fine for above code. Below is the code that I am using to dynamically create table.

```
    $scope.searchData = searchD;//search results(json) are coming in searchD variable
    var option="";
    $("#srchTable").remove();
    $("#dataCountinTable").after('<div id="tableDiv" class="table-responsive" style="width: 100%;">');   
    option += '<thead><tr><th>Name</th><th>Age</th><th>Salary</th></tr></thead>';
    for (var i = 0; i < searchD.length; i++) {
        option += '<tr><td><a id="A1" href="" ng-click="openDialog('+searchD[i].UserID+')">'+searchD[i].Name+'</a>'+
'</td><td>'+searchD[i].Age+'</td><td>'+searchD[i].Salary+'</td></tr>';
            }
            option += '</table>';
            //$("#srchTable").append(option);             
            //$("#srchTable").DataTable();

            //var temp = $compile(option)($scope);
            //angular.element(document.getElementById('srchTable')).append(temp);
            //$("#srchTable").DataTable();
```

Last 5 lines is the code that i tried to get `ng-click` work fine but all in vain. For `$compile` I am getting error `$compile is not defined`.
Also when table is initially loaded, link which is created is 
`<a id="A1" href="" ng-click="openDialog(sData.UserID)" class="ng-binding">Steve</a>`
and in dynamic created table, link is coming as 
`<a id="A1" href="" onclick="openDialog(1)">Steve</a>`
EDIT : Click is working because on click it is getting redirected to home page, but the method written on click is not getting called.

Comment: Why are you recreating the table with jQuery? You can just set the value of searchData in your controller the page will then automatically refresh. You will use the same piece of html as your first example to re-render. Please include the source code of your angular controller in your post.

Comment: @AndréVermeulen I was doing it before, but was facing an issue. Datatable was not getting refreshed with new data. I tried destroy(), clear() and a couple of other options for it but none of them worked. Then I finally tried by removing it and recreating which worked fine and now I am having this `ng-click` problem.

Comment: Ok... doing it with the Controller is the correct way. Something else was wrong there then. Rework your code to use the controller and then potentially update this post with that issue.

Comment: You should really use angular datatables - angular directives for dataTables; **and** you should create the table properly, render it by dataTables or angular using `searchData` as source, then the `ng-click` event will work too.

Comment: Can anyone tell me is there any issue with the code that I am writing?

Comment: where is that code at? is it inside a controller or a directive? `$compile` isn't available outside an angular context, and angular can't see HTML that is stored in JavaScript variables unless it is able to read the HTML **after** the content was added to the DOM, which is why `$compile` is necessary.

Comment: you should stop using Jquery with angular, it is very a bad practis! . put the data you want to display in var in the $scope, use this var in the view. If the data change in controller side the view will update itself

Comment: @Claies my `openDialog` method is written in controller and the part where I am dropping and recreating the table, that is also written inside controller only.

Comment: yes, but why are you even trying to do this at all instead of using `ng-repeat`?  I don't understand why you are trying to "dynamically create" the HTML, instead of just letting angular handle it.

Comment: @Claies because its not working. I'll expalin you. when on page load my table gets loaded, everything works fine. but when i click on search button and populate the data table again with new json then table is not getting refreshed i.e. old data stays as is in the table. I tried reload(), destroy(), clear() to re-populate table but nothig worked. so i dropped the table and dynamically created it with the new data. but now click is not working in that newly created table.

Comment: well the first problem is definitely more solvable than the second (what I mean is, figuring out why your data isn't refreshing is the problem you should solve).  Your potential solution here creates more issues than it solves.  You should consider making another attempt at getting your data to refresh, and posting about that issue if you can't get it to work, since that's the proper angular way to handle this kind of scenario.